# Issue with echo output to file in bash

Tags: bash, pyspark

I am running into an issue trying to echo some strings into files  inside a shell script.

I am calling the shell script through pyspark/spark's rdd.pipe() command, and I checked to make sure the input is coming through by echoing each line in the shell script.

Here is the shell script code:

```
#!/bin/sh
while read -r one; do
   read -r two
   read -r three
   read -r four
   read -r five
   read -r six
   read -r seven
   read -r eight
   echo -e "$one\n$two\n$three\n$four\n" >> 1.txt
   echo -e "$five\n$six\n$seven\n$eight\n" >> 2.txt
done
```

I ran the echo command WITHOUT piping to a file and that showed up in the output back in my spark program. The input to the shell script is just strings. Does anyone have ideas why 1.txt and 2.txt aren't being written to?

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that lets someone else see the problem themselves, without needing input files and a separate executable that aren't provided.

Comment: That said, note that `echo -e` is not guaranteed to do what you expect with `/bin/sh`. The POSIX sh specification requires that it print `-e` on output; bash using it as a toggle for escape sequence formatting is a standard-noncompliant extension. See [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/65819/3113) at [unix.se], or the [POSIX `echo` specification](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html) -- keeping in mind that even if your `/bin/sh` is provided by bash, it can be configured to turn off the extensions and behave to spec.

Comment: ...as for your real problem, though, I'd probably focus on figuring out what the current working directory is where the script is being invoked, and looking at whether your files are either being created somewhere you don't expect, or can't be created there at all due to lack of permissions. Though it could also be that there's just no input.

Comment: ...the "just no input" case can be eliminated if you replace the `>>1.txt` on the `echo` command with `>&3` with `3>1.txt` after the `done`, and likewise, change out the `>>2.txt` with `>&4`, with a `4>2.txt` after the `done`. That's also much more efficient as it's opening your output files only once per script run, vs the current behavior of reopening them every single time you want to add an additional line.

Comment: I am not clear what you mean? Could you retype my shell script out and replace what needs to be replaced?

Comment: Additionally, the executable isnt the issue atm the files themselves aren't even being written to.

Comment: If the executable isn't the issue, *take it out* when writing your reproducer. A reproducer should be something someone else can run *without changes* to see your problem themselves.

Comment: Okay I removed it, however it is hard to provide input for this task since it is in a weird formt(inside an RDD).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211895/discussion-between-charles-duffy-and-superwiz1).